# How to give permission specific user python pyramid?

Tags: python, pyramid

In python pyramid framework i could give permission in object level but how could i give permission in object level.i have group admin and moderator but in moderator group one user will give delete permission extra and in admin group one user will get less role than admin.

Comment: If you're not considering making use of granular permissions, I think what you could do is add a super moderator and a manager into your groups. And then for example in your review method you can set  (permission="Moderator,SuperModerator") and your delete method set (permission="SuperModerator")

Answer (score 0):

Websauna framework has an example to do this:

https://websauna.org/docs/narrative/crud/standalone.html#creating-crud-resources

Copy-pasting the answer to satisfy the deep desires of Stackoverflow overzealous moderators:

```
class ContractResource(Resource):
    """Map one TokenContract SQLAlchemy model instance to editable CRUD resource."""

    # __acl__ can be callable or property.
    # @reify caches the results after the first call
    @reify
    def __acl__(self) -> List[tuple]:
        # Give the user principal delete access as the owner
        # The returned list overrides __acl__ from the parent level
        # (ContractCRUD in our case)
        # See websauna.system.auth.principals for details
        contract = self.get_object()  # type: TokenContract
        if contract.owner:
            owner_principal = "user:{}".format(contract.owner.id)
            return [(Allow, owner_principal, "delete")]
        else:
            return []

    def get_title(self):
        token_contract = self.get_object()
        return "Smart contract {}".format(bin_to_eth_address(token_contract.contract_address))
```